# How to work SET statement in a DO loop in SAS?

Tags: sas

I studied SET statement in Do loop in SAS but i don't understand how to work SET statement in DO loop.

I create the following example dataset a1:

```
/* Create data a1 */

data a1 ; 
input fruit $ ; 
cards ; 
melon
apple
orange 
;
run ;

proc print data=a1 ; 
title "Results of a1" ; 
run;
```

Then, I create the following new dataset c1 :

```
/* Create data c1 using a1 -- This is a upper code block */

data c1 ;
do i = 1 to 3 ; 
    set a1 ; 
    count + 1 ;
    N_VAR = _N_ ; 
    ERR_VAR = _ERROR_ ;
    output ; 
end;
run ;

proc print data=c1 LABEL ; 
LABEL N_VAR = "_N_" ; 
LABEL ERR_VAR = "_ERROR_" ; 
title "Results of c1" ; 
run ;
```

Question: Why doesn't the upper code have the same output as the below code block? I don't understand how to work SET statement in a DO loop. What concept am I missing?

```
/* My expectation for c1 -- This is a below code block */

data my_expectation ; 
input i fruit $ count N  ERROR ;
cards ; 
1 melon 1 1 0
1 apple 2 2 0
1 orange 3 3 0
2 melon 4 1 0
2 apple 5 2 0
2 orange 6 3 0
3 melon 7 1 0 
3 apple 8 2 0
3 orange 9 3 0
;
run; 

proc print data=my_expectation label ;
LABEL N = "_N_" ; 
LABEL ERROR = "_ERROR_" ; 
title "The result that I expected for c1" ; 
run ;
```

I attached result image file below.

[image]

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: How could the output have more observations then the input id you are following each SET with only one OUTPUT?

Comment: @Tom I thought I would read the entire observation of the a1 dataset when i = 1 in Do-loop. I thought the same thing when i = 2 and i = 3 in Do-loop. So I expected a total of 3 (i = 1, 2, 3) * 3(apple, apple, orange) = 9 observations. However, contrary to expectation, when i=1, melon was read, when i=2, apple was read, and when i=3, orange was read. I couldn't understand this working process.

Comment: Presuming the expected result set is the same as the wanted result set, you are performing a cross join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `SET` statement sets up an independent reading stream.

A DATA step is an implicit loop.

After the `DO` loop iterates 3 times the implicit DATA step loop returns control to the top of the step.

At the second implicit iteration, the `DO` loop is entered, and in its first iteration the `SET` statement is reached (for the 4th time).  The input data set (`A1`) has no more observations, so the DATA step ends.

You can observe the flow behavior with this version of your DATA step:

```
data c1 ;
  put 'TOP';

do i = 1 to 3 ; 

put i= 'pre SET';

    set a1 ; 

put i= 'post SET';

    count + 1 ;
    N_VAR = _N_ ; 
    ERR_VAR = _ERROR_ ;
    output ; 
end;

  put 'BOTTOM';
run;
```

Aside:

When a DATA step does not have any explicit OUTPUT statements, the step will implicitly output an observation when control reaches the bottom of the step -- There are statements that prevent flow from reaching the bottom, such as, a `RETURN` statement or a subsetting `IF` statement that fails.

I answered your **why** question, @Tom showed you **how** to produce your expected result with DATA step.  The result is a cross join that SQL can also perform:

```
data a1 ; 
input fruit $ ; 
cards ; 
melon
apple
orange 
;

data replicates;
  do i = 1 to 3;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select i, a1.*
  from replicates cross join a1
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. Your answer is helpful to understand DATA Step working process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output each observation three times then move the DO loop after the SET.

```
set a1;
do i=1 to 3; output; end;
```

If you really want to read through the dataset three times then you either need three separate SET statements

```
i=1;
set a1;
output;
i=2;
set a1;
output;
i=3;
set a1;
output;
```

or use POINT= option to explicitly control which observation you are reading with the SET statement.

```
do i=1 to 3 ;
  do p=1 to nobs;
    set a1 point=p nobs=nobs ;
    output;
  end;
end;
stop;
```

Most DATA step stops when they read past the input and since that cannot happen with the POINT= option you need the STOP statement to prevent the data step from repeating forever.

Comment: WOW..The result of your last code block using POINT, NOBS was the result I wanted to make.